# Prove that any graph G with an even number of vertices has two vertices with an even number of common neighbour

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that any graph G with an even number of vertices has two vertices with an even number of common neighbors

Comment: Most people on SE don't like taking orders (I surely don't). Furthermore, what are your thoughts on the problem? Any ideas where you might start?

Comment: Maybe we can use handshaking theory？

Comment: I have thought for a long time but don't have many ideas.sorry.